# Need to know if between and like can be used together or something better in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison, between

Here is my query:

```
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM table_testcase_execution 
 WHERE campaign_session_id = any(SELECT campaign_session_id 
                                   FROM table_campaign_session 
                                  WHERE campaign_session_name = 'sitename') 
   AND timestamp BETWEEN "1288929643485" AND "1289010305536"
```

This works just fine, the problem is that I have to use a `LIKE` on these because they contain 3 extra digits (so this is a timestamp plus 3 digits).

Therefore I am using a `strtotime` in php and trying to match these in the database, but they contain the extra 3 digits. Is there a way I can redo this sql or add a `LIKE` clause for each of these timestamps?

```
      "1288929643485" AND "1289010305536"
```

Something like

```
 SELECT count(*) 
   FROM table_testcase_execution 
  WHERE campaign_session_id = any(SELECT campaign_session_id 
                                    FROM table_campaign_session 
                                   WHERE campaign_session_name = 'sitename') 
    AND timestamp between LIKE "1288929643%" AND "1289010305%"
```

Comment: Can you change the columns to DATETIME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the 3 extra digits can range from 000 to 999 then you could do something like this:

```
select count(*) from table_testcase_execution
where campaign_session_id = any(
    SELECT campaign_session_id
    FROM table_campaign_session
    WHERE campaign_session_name = 'sitename')
AND timestamp >= "1288929643000" AND timestamp <= "1289010305999"
```

This along with an index in `timestamp` column should give you good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the timestamps in your query are strings, can you not just truncate the unwanted three digits with [`SUBSTRING()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)?

```
select count(*) 
from table_testcase_execution 
where campaign_session_id = any(SELECT campaign_session_id FROM table_campaign_session WHERE campaign_session_name = 'sitename') 
AND timestamp between SUBSTRING(@timestamp1, -3) AND SUBSTRING(@timestamp2, -3)
```

(assuming @timestamp1 and @timestamp2 are the respective timestamp values supplied to the query...)